# Scala - How can I split an array of integers into tuples of 2 elements (coordinates)?

Tags: arrays, scala, list, tuples

I'm pretty new here so I'm not if I put this in the right section. I'm also very new to Scala.

Anyways, so I'm trying to read numbers from a text file (I guess they're strings here) and split them into pairs, in the order they are read but I'm having trouble dealing with:

- new lines
- splitting an array of numbers to pairs

Here's my code:

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  val file = Source.fromFile("/Users/donatkapesa/Desktop/poly.txt")
  val fileLines = file.getLines()

  while(fileLines.hasNext && !fileLines.isEmpty) {
    val array = fileLines.next.split(" ")
    //this doesn't take care of new lines. I have tried .split(" +") and .split("\\s+")

    // change the array elements to integers
    val intArray = array.map(array => array.toInt)

    // split array elements into tuples. But it doesn't work
    val coordinates = intArray.map(case Array(x,y) => (x,y))
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
io.Source
  .fromFile("poly.txt")    //open file
  .getLines                //read line-by-line
  .flatMap(_.split(" +"))  //split each line on the spaces
  .grouped(2)              //pair all strings /*sliding(2,2) also works*/
  .map{case List(a,b) => (a.toInt, b.toInt)}  //convert to Iterator[(Int,Int)]
  .toList                  //convert from Iterator to List (if desired)
```

Note that the conversion from `String` to `Int` is not safe here. The strings should be checked to be sure they consist of only digit characters. I've also done a shortcut on mapping the pairs of strings. If there are an odd number of strings for conversion then this `map()` will throw a `MatchError`. That can be avoided by adding `case List(a) => //do something with leftover`.